# Safari hidden selects causing input slowdown

Tags: performance, select, input, safari, hidden

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vJqy6/7/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div id="hiddenfields" style="display: none">

    </div>
    <input type="text" name="laggy" />
    <input type="text" name="fine" />
</form>
```

Javascript (for easy generation purposes):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#hiddenfields').append('<div><select name="hidden' + i + '"></select></div>');   
}

for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    $('#hiddenfields select').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
}
```

In safari 6.1 (on a mac) I am getting strange behaviour due to hidden select elements.
I found that if I have a bunch of large select fields in a hidden div in a form, then the first non-hidden text input has VERY laggy input.

To test the fiddle, just try typing any text in to the first text input at the lower right side and it should be slow and display one character every few seconds. If you increase the option count then you can force the slowdown to become worse, same goes with the select count. Typing in to the second text input works perfectly as expected!

My testing is on OS X Version 10.8.5

If I do a javascript profile from the web inspector, I come across certain methods that look like browser based ones with large slowdowns (note that this screenshot is not from testing on jsfiddle):
[image: JS Profile]

This issue was not in an older version of safari, and does not happen in chrome, firefox, IE. I have it open in chrome right now and it's smooth as butter

This leads me to believe it may be a bug in safari 6.1

- Any ideas on how to resolve this?
- Does this look like a browser bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a bug with Apple and it was eventually marked as a duplicate of another ticket. I can't view the other ticket using their bug tool. The other ticket is closed so if it was an actual bug then it is probably fixed in their development version or it may be "Not a bug" too

Comment: My apple support ticket is 15564550 and was marked as a duplicate of 14926967

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to link to tickets that I can see. The other ticket was marked as closed so it may be possible that it is resolved. I have been told that the issue is no longer happening but I haven't tested that myself